# How to change default apache folder to Flash drive on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, linux, apache-httpd

I have apache 2.4 on my raspberry pi and need to change DocumentRoot to flash drive folder.
But I have *403 Forbidden*.

In apache logs:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /media/pi/www/html/
```

and

```
AH00035: access to /index.html denied (filesystem path '/media/pi/www') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

I have read article on apache site for this error and make chmod like this, but it still forbidden:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available# namei -m /media/root/www/html/index.php
f: /media/root/www/html/index.php
 drwxr-xr-x /
 drwxr-xr-x media
 drwxr-xr-x root
 drwxr-xr-x www
 drwxr-xr-x html
 -rw-r--r-- index.php
```

Domian config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "/media/root/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /media/root/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

If change to origin /var/www - all works fine.

Comment: What is the filesystem on the flash drive?

Comment: What are the group and owner set to for files on the flash drive ? `ls -l /media/root/www/html` ? Also check that the flash drive is not mounted *read-only*

Comment: @techraf I tried with FAT32 first, this fs don't support premissions. Then I try ext4.

Comment: @KennetRunner 
`ls -l /media/root/www/html
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 20 янв 26 18:55 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  5 янв 26 18:56 text.txt
`

Comment: `mount | grep "media"` ?

Comment: @KennetRunner `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mount | grep "media"
/dev/mmcblk0p5 on /media/pi/SETTINGS type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda1 on /media/root/www type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)` I think that means that it's writable

Comment: Try using `/mnt` as a mount point instead of `/media`. The /media/pi directory is setup for user pi.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with virtual host config file. I am changing the default file only one line change is there...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        DocumentRoot /media/root/www/html
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

`DocumentRoot /media/pi/www/html` 
should be changed to your location which is 
`DocumentRoot /media/root/www/html/`

Also never forget to give permission to apache.

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /media/root/www/html/ -R
```

Comment: Sorry, I have pasted old config. I have updated it now. All is well with path, but still not working.